# No type or protocol named 'ComposeDelegate' error after adding bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

**XCode 12.1**

This project target gets compiler errors after an umbrella header is added [add swift functionality to an existing objective c target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO7PO.png)

Now there is an error of `No type or protocol named 'ComposeDelegate'` on all of the target's existing various `<ComposeDelegate>` declarations.

```
ComposeViewController.h

@class ComposeViewController;
@class DataModel;
@class Message;

// The delegate protocol for the Compose screen
@protocol ComposeDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didSaveMessage:(Message*)message atIndex:(int)index;
@end

// The Compose screen lets the user write a new message
@interface ComposeViewController : UIViewController /*<UITextViewDelegate>*/

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ComposeDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DataModel* dataModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPClient *client;
@end
```

[image]

Other similar code errors appear elsewhere in the target's code as well.

[image]

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: the warnings and errors pop up because its defined somewhere else already. The pre-compiler ignores the declaration and so more errors pop up. Guessing is `@class ComposeDelegate;` that is overdoo.

Comment: Tip: In general, when you get a warning or error - no surprise - the bug/mistake must be above the warning in code or project settings. So when searching for the problem you can always use `//` or `/* ... */` to out-comment some line and see the change.

Comment: Tip2: `/*<UITextViewDelegate>*/` is "dangerous" when it follows directly a ClassName. Make a line break directly before the out-commented code.

Comment: @OlSen , Thank you for the response. Do you find it odd that these warnings only show after a bridging header file was added?

Comment: nope, thats not odd to me. just an inconvenience from the past of Xcode. When the bridging header was generated automatically from Xcode this warnings should not appear. I use the search and replace tool quite often to repair and find stuff, that way you would also find if it was impl twice for real.

Comment: It was. It was fully functional before the bridging header was added

Comment: This actually depends on where, how and what kind of bridging header. Assuming Objc bridging to Swift. You don't re-import the header anywhere apart from project settings. Otherwise you create a ping pong game. A Bridging header can of course contain other bridging headers but there is one header that is used per project so far i remember.

Comment: So far, I created a new swift file in an objective c project, then Xcode asks to automatically create a bridging header. After clicking "create bridging header", the errors show up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224039/discussion-between-ol-sen-and-programcode).

Answer (score 1):

create a file for your protocol and copy the protocol declaration into that.

```
// ComposeDelegate.h

#idndef ComposeDelegate_h
#define ComposeDelegate_h

// The delegate protocol for the Compose screen
@protocol ComposeDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didSaveMessage:(Message*)message atIndex:(int)index;
@end

#endif
```

then use this file to include where ever you want.
While creating an extra file may seem extra work, it gives you more control of the pre-processing of your source.

The macro `#ifndef SomeName_h` ... `#endif` keeps the code from being implemented twice.

**PS:** If you code a `@interface` and the declared Class is not used earlier/above you don't have to and should not *pre-declare* the ClassName (`@class ComposeDelegate;`) if not really needed.

Comment: I tried making a new file named ComposeDelegate.h. Put the protocol inside it and imported it in the files with errors. Still getting errors. Still confused.